# Tracing to disk in VICE

Tags: emulator, commodore

The Versatile Commodore Emulator's monitor facility has support for tracing execution via the [`trace`](http://vice.pokefinder.org/doc/vice_12.html#SEC293) command. The (default?) behaviour of this command is to start writing out two lines per trace point encountered into the monitor.

However, the monitor window has a scrollback buffer of only 1000 lines. This means only the last 500 trace messages can be seen between two subsequent invocations of the monitor.

Is there a way to dump the trace log to a file instead?

Comment: Are you running it on Windows or another OS? And is the monitor's output going into its own window, or to the terminal/command prompt window you started VICE from (if you didn't start it from an icon)?

Comment: This is on Linux, and the monitor pops up in its own window. If it was tracing to the terminal, I could just redirect it to a file myself using pipes...

Comment: Yes, that's what I was going to suggest. Sorry I don't know about doing that with the monitor window; perhaps you could ask at https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/vice-emu-mail .